# How to Integrate SuperSet UI into React app

Tags: apache-superset

Is it possible to integrate the superset UI components into a react app?
I need that an Apache superset server is running and there is a React application that plugs in some of superset UI plugins and pulls data from the superset server.

Is there some way to achieve the above ?

Comment: Please let us know did you find any solution if yes can you please provide details

Comment: @Gaurav_soni did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Swagger UI based RESTful API used to access superset data endpoints. Refer to the link below.

[REST Documentation](https://preset.io/blog/2020-10-01-superset-api/)

Comment: Yes , they do provide the rest API. What I need is to embed the entire Superset visualization into my custom application.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: @Gaurav_soni I think, Iframe is the option to integrate with React App, but we need to bypass authentication to view charts. Did you find any solution?